# Shopify: Automatic Discount Detail On Product Detail Page

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, discount

I have created automatic discounts as special offer and I want to show it on product detail page.  I don't want to perform any calculation but wanted to notify customer that if they are buying the product now they will get an additional discount while checkout.

I tried several ways like adding a meta field on product but that take manual work and map each and every product as the discount will be applicable on the collection as well.

So, basically I want to access all available automate discounts on product detail page and display their details.

Please refer UI component that I want to render to Product page.

[image]